# Karate Skip test cases read from CSV in a Scenario Outline

Tags: csv, automated-tests, cucumber, karate, data-driven-tests

I'm writing data-driven-tests with Karate. My Feature has a Scenario Outline and I am using a CSV file to load the examples e.g. the test cases.

Is it possible to skip some rows in the CSV files? I don't want to call ALL the tests every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have three rows and you just want to run one. You can read the csv and then filter it using JsonPath filters. The following code will run only testcase "tc02".

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: CSV Filter

    Background:
        * def data = read('testdata.csv')
        * def data = get data[?(@.testcase=='tc02')]

    Scenario Outline: <testcase>,<desc>
        * def look = "<testcase>,<desc>"
        * print look

        Examples:
            | data |

# testdata.csv
# testcase,desc
# tc01,desc01
# tc02,desc02
# tc03,desc03
```

Comment: brilliant solution ! I would add that if you can have all the data as `Examples` - you could use tags: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags-and-examples